# how to use xpath via ui automator in appium

Tags: appium

appium version - 1.2.0

how to create xpath for using the element 'Data Usage' in attached
image

android version - 4.4.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use xpath. Use the `by.Name` locator strategy instead. Xpaths take much longer to process than using other locator strategies.

But if you need to use xpath, here's the answer:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//TextView[contains(@text,'Data usage')]"));`

[Read the xpath documentation for a better explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: I'm getting error 've seen in console observed that xml not found is displayed [Refer remoteobject.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this xpath.

```
android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Data usage')]
```